# what is the proper way to add urls to a third party app installed to my venv?

Tags: django

I have a third party app (django-allauth) which directs logins back to accounts/profile.

/accounts already includes the allauth urls.py file. I obviously do not want to go into my venv and start messing with the module itself, so what is the proper way to do this?

I can see two options. One is to just put accounts/profile ahead of the /accounts > include url which would catch it before it includes accounts, but I am not sure if this is the accepted django way to do this.

The other option I see is to create a dummy allauth directory with a urls.py that imports the other allauth urls.py and then redefines all of them or just adds what I need to them...

What would you do? I have not seen anything in the docs about this.

Comment: I wouldn't see an issue with altering the code in the third party urls.py to prevent this from happening. You can just comment out the specific section. If this does have a rippling effect (It shouldn't). Its better just removing this if its in your way, and changing it to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I didn't find an answer, I decided to just put my accounts/profile url ahead of the one that routed itself off to allauth, that way I would not lose the changes if allauth did some updates in the future.